# .htaccess url rewrting redirecting to 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^aboutus/our-mission/?$ our-mission.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am trying the above code in htaccess and resources like Js, Css are loading from aboutus/ instead of root and our-mission.php is at the root directory.

Comment: can you change the row orders for try ? 4->3 3->4

Comment: thank you that worked but resources like css ,js are not loading on the redirect

Comment: try this in 3. row `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]`

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpeg|gif|png)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^aboutus/our-mission/?$ our-mission.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

but resources are still loading form aboutus instead of root

Comment: _"and resources like Js, Css are loading from aboutus/ instead of root and our-mission.php is at the root directory"_ - congratulations, you have just observed how resolving relative URLs into absolute ones works. And if you go and do a little more research on that topic, you'll find that using URLs relative to the domain, so starting with a slash, is the most common solution to this problem that gets asked about every other day ...

Answer (score 0):

There are exceptions and priorities for .htaccess rows. Here is a fix.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^aboutus/our-mission/ our-mission.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer but 
it is giving 500 internal server error

Comment: can you try updated answer